# How to set nvd3 lineChart x-axis to use string

Tags: python, d3.js, nvd3.js, python-nvd3

I'm a complete noob, I wish to plot a lineChart using the python wrapper of the `nvd3` library built on top of `d3.js`. I've been exploring the `x_axis_format` of the lineChart and desire to utilize custom formatting so I can use strings on x-axis . 
The `NVD3` base class from the [documentation](http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes-doc/NVD3Chart.html) states `create_x_axis(name, label=None, format=None, date=False, custom_format=False)`, 
and from [NVD3/lineChart.py](https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/blob/develop/nvd3/lineChart.py):

```
if kwargs.get('x_is_date', False):
            self.set_date_flag(True)
            self.create_x_axis('xAxis',
                               format=kwargs.get('x_axis_format', '%d %b %Y'),
                               date=True)
            self.set_custom_tooltip_flag(True)
else:
    if kwargs.get('x_axis_format') == 'AM_PM':
          self.x_axis_format = format = 'AM_PM'
    else:
       format = kwargs.get('x_axis_format', 'r')
       self.create_x_axis('xAxis', format=format,
       custom_format=kwargs.get('x_custom_format', False))
```

But when I do this:

lineChart(name="lineChart-With-Interactive-Guideline",height=400, width=800, x_is_date=False, custom_format=False, use_interactive_guideline=True)

I get an empty page, no chart. 
Can someone please show me how to set my x-axis to allow string values such as "2016-07-01", "2016-07-02"?

Answer (score 0):

You must use lineChart x_axis_format argument with a format string, i.e.:  x_axis_format='%d/%b/%Y'

After that, you need to set the chart.add_serie x value to a list of timestamps, as the timestamp is not in Unix Epoch, multiply them by 1000:

xdata = [(datetime.timestamp(x+timedelta(days=1)))*1000 for x in df["date"]]

chart.add_serie( x=xdata )